# Google Speech-to-Text JupyterLab notebook script run locally using Google Cloud SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, sdk, speech-to-text

I have the following Python script which runs fine on a Google JupyterLab notebook but not locally using Google Cloud SDK:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1

def speech_to_text(audio_file):

    client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient()

    enable_word_time_offsets = True
    enable_word_confidence = True
    enable_automatic_punctuation = True

    language_code = 'en-US'
    config = {
        'enable_word_confidence': enable_word_confidence,
        'enable_word_time_offsets': enable_word_time_offsets,
        'enable_automatic_punctuation': enable_automatic_punctuation,
        'language_code': language_code
    }
    audio = {'uri': audio_file}
    operation = client.long_running_recognize (config, audio)
    response = client.recognize(config, audio)
    result = response.results[0]
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]

    print(alternative)
    
speech_to_text('gs://my-bucket/my-folder/my-subfolder/my-audio-file.flac')
```

However, when I try to run this script locally (WIN10, Python 3.8) in a virtual environment using the Google Cloud SDK I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-speech-to-text-script.py", line 32, in <module>
    speech_to_text('gs://my-bucket/my-folder/my-subfolder/my-audio-file.flac')
  File "my-speech-to-text-script.py", line 25, in speech_to_text
    operation = client.long_running_recognize (config, audio)
TypeError: long_running_recognize() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I followed this tutorial for setting up the virtual environment https://cloud.google.com/python/setup#windows and then I ran `pip install google-cloud-speech`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by updating my code, which like yours, may have been based on an older version of the Speech-to-Text library.

The important change:

```
operation = client.long_running_recognize(request={"config":config, "audio":audio})
```

Answer (score 2):

This solved my problem, thank you very much. Here is the code which is working now:

```
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1

def speech_to_text(audio_file):

    client = speech_v1p1beta1.SpeechClient()

    enable_word_time_offsets = True
    enable_word_confidence = True
    enable_automatic_punctuation = True

    language_code = "en-US"
    config = {
        "enable_word_confidence": enable_word_confidence,
        "enable_word_time_offsets": enable_word_time_offsets,
        "enable_automatic_punctuation": enable_automatic_punctuation,
        "language_code": language_code
    }
    audio = {"uri": audio_file}
    operation = client.long_running_recognize(request={"config":config, "audio":audio})
    response = client.recognize(request={"config":config, "audio":audio})
    result = response.results[0]
    alternative = result.alternatives[0]

    print(alternative)
    
speech_to_text('gs://my-bucket/my-folder/my-subfolder/my-audio-file.flac')
```